# How to convert a ResultEvent from amfphp into array collection flex?

Tags: arrays

how can I convert a source.result from AMFPHP into ArrayCollection? the function I'm trying without success is the following:

```
public function listrecordsmail(source:ResultEvent,arrayDefinitionsargs:Array):void {

//listamailsend.dataProvider = source.result;


    var array:Array = ArrayUtil.toArray(source.result);
    SearchLoadlistOneDP = new ArrayCollection(array);
    SearchLoadlistOneDP.refresh();

}
```

Thanks to everyone now

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
SearchLoadlistOneDP = source.result as ArrayCollection;
```

Thanks all.